# Make a checkbox group disappear

Tags: component, custom-component, custom-field, custom-action

I am using BreezingForms and I have a checkbox group that look for files into my database. It is possible that there is no item to select in the database; at this moment, I want the checkbox group to disappear. I am also open to another solution, like change the checkbox group, in the case of no item, into a field that will display "No items".

Currently, when there is no item, the only field in my checkbox group is "No item" (with a checkbox next to it) and the name of the checkbox "Your items:".

Have you an answer or an idea for resolve that difficulty?

Comment: I have no recent experience with BF and don't know how the rendering of the form/fields is done - but if there is a way to inject some php before the render happens, you could check if there are items and decide upon showing that field. If this is not possible, you could use some js to check that field and hide/modify it on the fly, after page has been loaded.

Comment: Breezingforms offers such functionality form settings -> form pieces -> "before form". You can even write a script and add it there. I would check the data there and change the field output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS to hide the field in your form - just check which CSS class (or which id) is assigned to the HTML element that you want to hide (or one of its parents), and then add a CSS rule to hide it (remember, you can select the *nth* child element of any HTML element through CSS, and then assign the `display:none` to that element).

Having said that, if I were given the choice between BreezingForms and RS Forms, I'd go with the latter.